# How to give an example of a $f$ differentiable in a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f^\prime(x)$ doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

How would I give a simple example of a function $f$ differentiable in a deleted neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f^\prime(x)$ does not exist? I cannot seem to think of an example.

A delete neighborhood is an open interval about $x_0$ which does not contain $x_0$. So, $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)-\{x_0\}$ for some $\delta>0$.

How would something be differentiable in a deleted neighborhood if at the point of the derivative, the limit does not exist. Presumably, the derivative ends up looking something like $\lim_{x\to x_0} \dfrac{1}{x}$, if it does not exist.

Comment: Must be your function continuous?

Comment: @Dog_69 No, it can be any function we can dream up

Comment: I was thinking about the Heaviside's function but I will say the absolute value $|x|$ around $x=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic example:
$$\sqrt[3]{(x-x_0)^2}$$

Answer (score 6):

Take $f(x) = x \sin (1/x)$ near $0$

Answer (score 4):

You may try $f(x)=x^2\cos(1/x)$, so that $f'(x)=2x\cos(1/x)-\sin(1/x)$ has a point of discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: This is a slightly better example than mine, in fact, because $f$ is differentiable at zero as well.

Answer (score 2):

Does $f(x)=x^\frac 12 $ count?
$f'(x)=\frac 1{2x^\frac 12}$  which is discontinuous at $x=0$

Comment: Yes, it does! But see my remark on $x^2 \cos 1/x$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$$

If you are looking for that exact derivative.